# excluding web.config with msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, teamcity

I have below msbuild which is executed by team city. I want to exclude web.config but cannot do. In code below you can see i added code but it doesnt work. I am totally novice in msbuild and teamcity

```
<property name="solution.dir" value="." />
<property name="SolutionFileName" value="MyProj.sln" />
<property name="projectfile" value="${solution.dir}\MyDir\Myproj.csproj" />
<property name="MSBuildPath" value="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" />
<ItemGroup>
<MyProjectReferences Exclude="web.config" />
</ItemGroup>
<target name="build" depends="clean,UpdateBuildVersion,compile" />
<target name="clean" description="delete build artifacts">
  <property name="build.base" value="${solution.dir}/_deploy/" />
  <property name="dir.publish" value="${build.base}/publish" />
  <property name="dir.package" value="${build.base}/package" />
  <property name="project.fullversion" value="1.0.0.1" />

</target>
<target name="compile" description="compile">

  <exec program="${MSBuildPath}" failonerror="true">
   <arg value="${projectfile}" />
   <arg line="/p:Configuration=Release" />
   <arg line="/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True" />
   <arg line="/p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False"/>
   <arg line="/t:Rebuild" />
   <arg line="/t:Package" />
   <arg line="/p:IncludeAppPool=true" />
   <arg line="/p:PackageLocation=${solution.dir}/../publish/package/Myproj.zip" />
  <arg line="/P:DeployIisAppPath=website/MyProj" />
  <!--<arg line="-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=.*web\.config"></arg>-->

  </exec>
 </target>
```

Can somebody point me to right direction?

Comment: btw: This doesn't contain the entire xml build script. Can you post the entire file, and not the... last half?

Comment: @CJohnson i think i posted relevant code. Rest was crap and commented out. May be closing tags are missing but thats it i think

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to start, the syntax for the build is way off. But you are new to msbuild. So I have tried to interpret what it is you would need based off of what you gave us here.

So here is your script somewhat reinterpreted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="Choose something else here too">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SolutionDir>C:\Some\Path\Where\You\Keep\your\Solution\</SolutionDir>
    <BuildDir>C:\Some\Path\where\your\build\goes\that\is\outside\of\your\repo\</BuildDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MyProject include="$(SolutionDir)MyDir\MyProj.csproj" >
      <Properties>Condiguration=Release;UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True;PipelineDependsOnBuild=False;IncludeAppPool=true;PackageLocation=$(SolutionDir);DeployIisAppPath=website\MyProj</Properties>
    </MyProject>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target name="clean">
    <!-- The best thing to do is to call msbuild with the clean target. -->
    <MSBuild Projects="@(MyProject)" Targets="Clean" />
    <!-- Then delete anything else you want to -->
    <Delete Files="" />
    <!-- I like to just delete the build directory for cleaning -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BuildDir)" />
  </Target>

  <Target name="updateBuildVersion">
    <!-- Do what ever you need to here. -->
  </Target>

  <Target name="Build" DependsOnTargets="clean;updateBuildVersion">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(MyProject" Targets="Build" StopOnFirstFailure="true" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment back here if you have questions and I'll do my best to help answer them.

Comment: where you delete web.config?

Comment: A file like web.config seems it's going to be an 'item' in the MyProj.csproj file. So that file (Which you have not posted) is the one that includes or excludes web.config.

Comment: i didnt understood what you meant. do you mean i write like <MyProject exclude="$(SolutionDir)MyDir\web.config" >

Comment: I have no idea what web.config is supposed to be, or what it's supposed to be doing. Anyways web.config should not be in this file at all.